# Best way to code: Dynamically allocated rows in TableLayout with onClickListener() required for each row?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am trying to add rows in a tableLayout dynamically with click events trigerring some action for each row. The data is dynamic because it is coming from the server.

I have come upon two different ways to use the dynamic approach and registering the click events.

For dynamic approach the easiest way would be to put the rowAdditon() as  a dedicate function like

```
tl.addView(row1);
tl.addView(row2);
```

and to integrate click events i would require each TableRow object for onCLickListener().

But i am not able to find the best way to integrate them together.

First thing that comes to my mind is a ArrayList. Is there any other easy way to acheive this.

i tried to implement this like the following

```
    ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();
            DataBaseReceiverForConnectToTeachers received=new DataBaseReceiverForConnectToTeachers(this);
            int count=received.getNoOfData();
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
                a1.add("t"+i);
            }

            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
              TableRow  a1.get(i)=new TableRow(this);
//getting error in this line
//cannot resolve method get(int)
//a1 is already define in the scope
            }
```

The solution was creating a for loop that runs for the size of the items in database.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to put into table view , add the same in linear layout by creating it in xml and whenever you want to add button call a method and keep the id of this button static so that you can make every button on click method separately

Let me know if my answer completes your query else I can provide you code for this

Comment: how can i achieve dynamic nature out of it?